Scenarios where logistic regression gives much higher AUC than naive Bayes
It is my understanding that in the absence of covariation among predictor variables, logistic regression and naive Bayes should give nearly equivalent results with respect to predictive accuracy (as measured by ROC/AUC etc).
I am trying to reconcile this with the observation of much higher predictive accuracy using logistic regression than naive Bayes for a set of simulated data.
Briefly, I am simulating a very simple model of genotype-phenotype map where there are n sites (loci) i=1...n, each of which has either a 0 or 1 allele with a certain probability p_i. At each locus, a 0 allele corresponds to "wildtype" and a 1 corresponds to "risk", i.e. a 1 allele at the ith site is associated with an odds ratio OR_i > 1. The disease (or some binary phenotype) risk of each genotype is calculated by taking the product of OR_i over all sites, and a control/disease phenotype is assigned with a probability proportional to this OR with respect to some baseline value. Note that in this, the simplest case, the effect of each site is statistically independent, i.e. OR multiplicate across sites.
Nevertheless, for this simple multiplicative model of genotype-phenotype map, I consistently find much higher AUC for logistic regression classifiers than those using naive Bayes (I'm performing logistic regression using glm family=binomial in R, and I'm using the naiveBayes function in the e1071 R library, both with default settings).
I'm trying to figure out a plausible explanation for why logistic regression gives a better performance.

AUC varying what? Threshold?

Could you please clarify your question? I'm simulating 1000 genotypes according to the model described above, and use 500 as a training set to predict phenotype and then calculate AUC based on logistic regression or naive Bayes prediction on the test set.

AUC is the area under a curve, and to make that curve, you need "different variations of your model", so I'm asking, what are you changing/carying to create the  curve?

In different iterations, I increase the expected OR value per risk allele at each site.

The point is that whether the expected per site OR is large or small, the effects across sites are statistically independent. Despite this fact, in every iteration there is a higher false negative/positive rate using naive Bayes as the predictor. My question is basically whether it is possible to get highly divergent performance between logistic regression and naive Bayes in a scenario where the covariance among predictors is effectively zero.

Without access to your code, it is difficult to tell whether this is actually an error or a feature of your data. At least without knowing more about your data and results (number of loci, hold big are the probabilities, numerical train/test set errors for both models) it will be hard to say what is going on.
